# Is there a more convenient way to represent (1,2+3,4) m with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

### Background:

- I want all decimal numbers in my TeX input file use `.` as the decimal separator.
- If my document is translated to German (for example), the `.` can be globally converted to `,` by `locale` option.
- Now consider if I want to output `(1,2+3,4) m` in the translated version but `(1.2+3,4) m` in the original version.
- Using `$\num{1.2}+\num{3.4}$\si{\m}$` produces an output with incorrect spacing between the `)` and `m`.
- Using `$\SI{(1.2+3.4)}{\m}$` throws an error.
- Using `$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(1.2+3.4)}{\m}$` will ignore `locale=DE` option so the output will use `.` rather than `,`.
- Using `$\SI[parse-numbers=false]{(1{,}2+3{,}4)}{\m}$` will make my translator unhappy.

### MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\def\x{1.23}
\def\y{4.56}

\def\X{1{,}23}
\def\Y{4{,}56}
\begin{document}
$\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
L &= \SI{\x}{\m} + \SI{\y}{\m}\\
    &= (\num{\x}+\num{\y})\si{\m}
\end{aligned}
$

$\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
L &= \SI{\x}{\m} + \SI{\y}{\m}\\
    &= \SI[parse-numbers=false]{(\x+\y)}{\m}
\end{aligned}
$

$\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
L &= \SI{\x}{\m} + \SI{\y}{\m}\\
    &= \SI[parse-numbers=false]{(\X+\Y)}{\m}
\end{aligned}
$


\end{document}
```

### Questions:

Is there a more convenient way to represent `(1,2+3,4) m` in the translated version without using `parse-numbers=false` and `xxx{,}yyy` ugly trick while maintaining the correct spacing?

Comment: `$(\num{\x}+\num{\y})\,\si{\m}$` will give you correct spacing and a translated decimal separator (but it's not very convenient, of course).

Comment: @Jake: Actually I have the same idea but I don't know the correct spacing macro for that.

Comment: Could you maybe use the `\SIrange` command or a modified version of it?

Comment: Why do you use `{,}` inside `\def\Y{4{,}56}`?

Comment: @Bugbusters: Now you do `=)`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: Because I also use it in `\X`. `parse-numbers=false` makes `locale=DE` no longer work.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen: It  has nothing to do with ranging I think.

Comment: I don't think that the output of `$(\num{\x}+\num{y})\si{m}$` is incorrect. The thin space is necessary only between a number and a unit, but here you have a parentheses.

Comment: This does just look like a range: what is wrong with `\SIrange{1.23}{4.56}{\metre}`?

Comment: @egreg My reading of the meaning of the space here (it shows the fact that a quantity is a product of a number and a unit) means that you still need a space with the parenthetic version.

Comment: @JosephWright: Why is `\SIrange{}` relevant?

Comment: @JosephWright Physicists always have strange ideas about mathematical notation. ;-) The space isn't really necessary between a number and a unit: people have written `$2a$` for centuries, after all. It's just a convention in the case a unit follows a *number*, to avoid ambiguities; what ambiguity can arise here? I'd say the space would be ambiguous, instead.

Comment: @Bugbusters Because you can set it up so that it works like you want the sum to work: `\newcommand*{\SIsum}[4][]{\SIrange[range-phrase=+, range-units = brackets, #1]{#2}{#3}{#4}}`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: It does not make sense if I have 3 operands or even more. :-)

Comment: @Bugbusters Then `\SIlist`: `\newcommand*{\SIsum}[3][]{\SIlist[list-separator=\ensuremath{{}+{}}, list-final-separator=\ensuremath{{}+{}}, list-units = brackets, #1]{#2}{#3}}` (The `\ensuremath` stuff isn’t needed if you don’t use this outside of math-mode.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Is it possible to handle `(1,23+4,56x7,89-0,12/3,56) m`?

Comment: @Bugbusters No, it is not. You will need your own parser then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `siunitx` package already handles products and quotients quite well, with a few auxiliary macros we can make `+` and `-` act as splitters for `\num`.

The correct `inter-unit-product` is taken from `siunitx` directly.

The second example shows one disadvantage of this approach: unitary signs need to be braced so that our own parser doesn’t see it. (Also, it misses some parentheses.) Though, I don’t see much use in them as minuses can simply replace the preceding `+`.

A better approach would be to use `siunitx`’/LaTeX 3’s already present facilities to parse the argument to `\SI` or `\num` similar to products and quotients (which may contradict their usage as `\pm` input literals).

The typesetting of the parentheses around all numbers is out-sourced to `mathtools` and its `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` macro. The new `siunitx` key `any` can be used to customize the optional argument/star to the delimiters (see examples).

And old version of the `\SIany` macro that takes one optional `*` (`\SIany*…`)/an optional argument in parenthesis (`\SIany(\big)`) which get forwarded to `mathtools` delimiter can be seen in [revision 7](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/111257/7) of this answer.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}

\makeatletter
% copied from pgfutil-common.tex
\newif\ifqrr@in@
\def\qrr@in@#1#2{%
 \def\qrr@in@@##1#1##2##3\qrr@in@@{%
  \ifx\qrr@in@##2\qrr@in@false\else\qrr@in@true\fi}%
 \qrr@in@@#2#1\qrr@in@\qrr@in@@}
\def\qrr@in#1#2{\qrr@in@{#1}{#2}\ifqrr@in@\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
%

% Splitter
\def\parse@stop{\parse@stop}
\def\parse@numbers@split@plus#1+#2\parse@stop{\parse@numbers{#1}+\parse@numbers{#2}}
\def\parse@numbers@split@minus#1-#2\parse@stop{\parse@numbers{#1}-\parse@numbers{#2}}

%
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\qrr@siunitx@p}{(}{)}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\qrr@siunitx@p@star{*}
\keys_define:nn { siunitx }{
    any .code:n = 
        \def\@tempa{#1}
        \ifx\qrr@siunitx@p@star\@tempa
            \def\qrr@siunitx@p@params{*}
        \else
            \expandafter\def\expandafter\qrr@siunitx@p@params
                \expandafter{\expandafter[\csname#1\endcsname]}
        \fi
}
\sisetup{any=}
\newcommand*\SIany[3][]{
    \begingroup
        \sisetup{#1}
        \expandafter\qrr@siunitx@p\qrr@siunitx@p@params{\parse@numbers{#2}}%
        \l__siunitx_unit_product_tl
        \si{#3}
    \endgroup}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Parser
\def\parse@numbers#1{%
    \qrr@in+{#1}
        {\parse@numbers@split@plus#1\parse@stop}
        {%
            \qrr@in-{#1}
                {\parse@numbers@split@minus#1\parse@stop}
                {\num{#1}}
        }%
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
$ \SIany{1.23 + 4.56 x 7.89 - 0.12 / 3.56}{\m} $

$ \SIany{1.23 + {-}4.56 x 7.89 - 0.12 / 3.56}{\m} $

\sisetup{quotient-mode=fraction}
$ \SIany{1 + 0.12 / 3.56}{\m} = \SIany[any=*]{1 + 0.12 / 3.56}{\m} = \SIany[any=big]{1 + 0.12 / 3.56}{\m} $
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: (1) Maybe the line `(\parse@numbers#2\parse@stop)%` should be replaced by `\left(\parse@numbers#2\parse@stop\right)%`. (2) How do I change the spacing between the number and unit from `\ ` to `\,`?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg **(1)** Not really, as `\left` and `\right)` might produce too big delimiters. I added the functionality of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from the `mathtools` package. A `\SIany*` forwards the `*` to the delimiter, as well the optional `()` argument does. (The examples do hopefully make this clear.) [Note that `siunitx` has some form of bracket/parentheses functionality with lists and ranges, which could be extended to these delimiters, too.] **(2)** The default spacing is `\,` and can be set by the mentioned `inter-unit-product` option of `siunitx`.

Comment: (1) Good point. (2) Hmmm. It just looks like `\ ` to me, but it is nice if it isn't.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg **(1)** I have introduced a new `siunitx` key instead of that weird first optional argument of `\SIany`: The `any` key! **(2)** Compare: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{siunitx}\begin{document}\ExplSyntaxOn\fbox{\l__siunitx_unit_product_tl}\par\fbox{\,}\end{document}`. It’s the same spacing as around `+`, `-` or `\times` (a thin one).

Comment: This is really great. Good job!